# using Getserversideprops inside page to fetch data from strapi, still getting undefined as the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

so i am trying to fetch data from strapi backend using getServerSideprops in nextjs but the data i am getting is undefined even tho the link works just fine inside browser, and yes i am fetching inside a page not inside a component using same method as described in docs what i am doing wrong ?

```
function Products({props}) {
  console.log(props); //<-- returns undefined 

  return (
    <div className=''>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/products?populate=*`)
  const data = await res.json()
console.log(data) //<-- returns undefined 
  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } }
}


export default Products;
```

Comment: You have a code comment indicating that the response from your API is already `undefined`. If so, wouldn't you expect the data to be `undefined` in the component as well?

Comment: actually i wrote those comments to indicate that this data returns undefined in console

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `data` into your component via `getServerSideProps`, so you should destructure accordingly:

```js
function Products({data}) {
  console.log(data);
  ...
}
```

You can also log your full props object like so:

```
function Products(props) {
  console.log(props);
  ...
}
```

Comment: tried the second one and now it returns a null object that have "[[Prototype]]
: Object" inside

Comment: Then it seems to me that your API endpoint is not returning the expected value. If you visit the API endpoint in your browser, does it respond with the expected result?

Comment: Yes I opened it in browser and it's giving me correct data , it's confusing because same code worked in my previous projects , i think I should use other methods like react queries or axios